# didExitRegion trigger when i'm inside the region ios

Tags: ios, geofencing

i'm monitoring regions in my app and sometimes `didExitRegion` is called when i'm inside the region.
Is there any solution to avoid that ?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the radius to see if that has an effect?  If your radius value is small enough and your gps signal is low then the accuracy may be causing you to move in and out of the region, though you aren't moving.

Comment: I tried with 150m and still not working.